# angularjs include template does not run main javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I noticed something while working angularjs. I have a templates folder end it has a file named **menu.html**

menu.html file contains html elements. my main page includes javscript code that polulates menu.html elements.

I am calling menu.html in main page like this:

```
<div ng-include="'templates/menu.html'"></div>
```

But javascript code not working. If I write javascript code in menu.html, it works. included menu.html does not work with Jquery or other references.

Comment: Have you any errors in the console ? By the way : this <div ng-include="'templates/menu.html'"></div> should be <div ng-include="templates/menu.html"></div> (remove the ')

Comment: javascript included from a template does not get parsed.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will not execute any JavaScript code contained in a partial specified via templateUrl (or template).

To get around this I use a directive that has angular lazy load the javascript.

```
app.directive('script', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            if (attr.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
                var code = elem.text();
                /*jslint evil: true */
                var f = new Function(code);
                f();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

On your menu.html

```
<script type="text/javascript-lazy">
  // javascript code here
</script>
```